# Is “I no longer know If I wish to drown myself in love, vodka or the sea.” a real Franz Kafka quote?

Tags: quote-source, franz-kafka

It is attributed to him on various famous quote sites but strikes me as spurious.
the only source attribution is to Letters to Milena but I haven't read it in years and don't have a copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest version of this quote that I was able to find appeared on Twitter in February 2013.

> i don't know if i want to drown myself in love, vodka, or the sea
>
> <sub>@ChilllSlut, [2013-02-18 11:15](https://twitter.com/ChilllSlut/status/303643859903184896). twitter.com.</sub>

The quote became popular on Twitter immediately: if you do your own searches, you'll find many hundreds of instances. The attribution to ChilllSlut was quickly stripped, but it took a while for the attribution to Kafka to be added: the earliest instance of this that I was able to find is from
[bunsonganak05 on Instagram in 2016](https://www.instagram.com/p/BNus7TdgYz9/). The false attribution was copied to collections of quotations, and from there into print in 2019:

> “I no longer know if I wish to drown myself in love, vodka or the sea.” — Franz Kafka
>
> <sub>Hugo Chandler, ed. (2019). [*Franz Kafka… Whispers in Prague*, p. 14](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Whispers_in_Prague/Lz7VDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA14). novum publishing.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I found a [searchable file online](https://issuu.com/sumyatswezin/docs/letters_to_milena.pptx) of *Letters to Milena*. (It's more readable [here](http://www.kkoworld.com/kitablar/frans_kafka_milenaya_mektublar-eng.pdf) but not searchable.) The word "drown" appears six times, but none of them is in anything resembling this phrase.

A [couple of](https://soundcloud.com/madeline-shaffer/or-the-sea) other [online sources](https://quozio.com/quote/fe0c7bec/1025/i-no-longer-know-if-i-wish-to-drown-myself-in-love-vodka-or) attribute the same quote to Grantaire from *Les Misérables*, but searching [that text](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-h/135-h.htm) for "drown" was similarly fruitless.